# python timer mystery

Tags: python, timer, signals

Well, at least a mystery to me.  Consider the following:

```
import time
import signal

def catcher(signum, _):
    print "beat!"

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, catcher)
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 2, 2)

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
```

Works as expected i.e. delivers a "beat!" message every 2 seconds. Next, no output is produced:

```
import time
import signal

def catcher(signum, _):
    print "beat!"

signal.signal(signal.SIGVTALRM, catcher)
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_VIRTUAL, 2, 2)

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
```

Where is the issue?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `time.sleep(5)` in the second program to `pass`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From my system's man setitimer (emphasis mine):

> The  system  provides each process with three interval timers, each decrementing in a **distinct time domain**.  When any timer expires, a signal is sent to the process, and the timer (potentially) restarts.
>
> ITIMER_REAL    **decrements in real time**, and delivers SIGALRM upon expiration.
>
> ITIMER_VIRTUAL **decrements only when the process is executing**, and delivers SIGVTALRM upon expiration.

Did you just miss that your process isn't executing while sleeping?  It's going to take an awfully long time for you to accrue actually-used time with that loop.

Comment: It looks like a good explanation to me. When you do `time.sleep()`, your process is suspended (i.e. not executing). If you changed it to `pass`, your process would execute and consume time.

Comment: How silly of me!!!  The above was just a quick test to see how timer signals work... newbie (on signals) error. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

The `signal.ITIMER_VIRTUAL` only counts down with the process is running.  `time.sleep(5)` suspends the process so the timer doesn't decrement.