# feedparser with timeout

Tags: python, feedparser

My code got stuck on this function call:

```
feedparser.parse("http://...")
```

This worked before. The url is even not possible to open in the browser.
How would you cure this case? Is there a timeout possibility? I'd like to continue as if nothing would happen (only with printing some message or log this issue)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can specify timeout globally using `socket.setdefaulttimeout()`.

The timeout may limit how long an individual socket operation may last -- `feedparser.parse()` may perform many socket operations and therefore the total time spent on dns, establishing the tcp connection, sending/receiving data may be much longer. See [Read timeout using either urllib2 or any other http library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684677/4279).

Comment: OK, I used it but don't know if it works because the URL with endless loading is active again.

Answer (score 24):

Use Python `requests` library for network IO, feedparser for parsing only:

```
# Do request using requests library and timeout
try:
    resp = requests.get(rss_feed, timeout=20.0)
except requests.ReadTimeout:
    logger.warn("Timeout when reading RSS %s", rss_feed)
    return

# Put it to memory stream object universal feedparser
content = BytesIO(resp.content)

# Parse content
feed = feedparser.parse(content)
```

Comment: It is better than specifying the global timeout but it might not fix the issue due to the reason pointed out in my answer (`requests.get()` may block for much longer than the `timeout` value). Follow the link for details.

Comment: I like this solution. I have http settings that work really well for my purposes, but wanted to feedparser for the variations I find in rss feeds. This allows me to do both. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

According to the author's recommendation[1], you should use requests library to do http request, and parse result to feedparser.

[1] https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/pull/80

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick workaround you can monkey patch and use requests lib instead with proper timeout. It also fixes https certificate issues I had with default feedparser url open implementation. This is how I do it:

```
feedparser._open_resource = lambda *args, **kwargs: feedparser._StringIO(requests.get(args[0], timeout=5).content)
```

Update: On versions above 6.x use following:

```
feedparser.api._open_resource = lambda *args, **kwargs: requests.get(args[0], headers=headers, timeout=5).content
```

All rights reserved by [darklow](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/issues/76#issuecomment-312922034)